# Shell interaction using Python and extracting the response for further logic

Tags: python

**Problem Statement**:

1. Execute a groovy script in shell using Python
2. The Shell would request for password and display "Password:"
3. Need to check if that is displayed and provide a password.
4. Verify the output as "Approved"

My code looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import time


process = subprocess.Popen(['groovy', 'some.groovy -u param1 -h param2-p param3'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(5)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print stdout

#Now id the output says "Password:", I need to provide it and then again check if shell displays "Approved"
```

Comment: Is Python a strict requirement? This is probably easier to do in straight Bash.

Comment: Yes. Python is the requirement.